# Error importing flask python google app engine (pydev on eclipse)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, pydev

I'm working on my first web app on google app engine using python and flask. My machine is running Ubuntu 15.04, 64 bits.

Problem is that after following all the directions in the tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env, I get an error that python is not able to import flask. I get the following error in the eclipse SDK:

```
Unresolved import: Flask    main.py /flask-app  line 2  PyDev Problem
```

I checked and the flask folder is in my app's "lib" directory.

Any ideas what it is that I'm missing?

Added:

1) I completely removed gcloud, eclipse, pydev, the workspace folder, everything. Then reinstalled step by step and still get the same error.

2) Tried different approaches to include flask in the Pydev $PYTHONPATH:

- Copied flask to the app's root directory
- Added source folders for the flask folder, the lib folder and the lib/flask folder. Even though the different flask folders appear in the tree, they don't get resolved.

Here's the screenshot:[image]

3) Contents of my main.py file: (the error is on the 2nd line, from...)

```
import logging

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
# Log the error and stacktrace.
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return 'An internal error occurred.', 500
```

Comment: If you just do: `import flask`, does it work or is just that also set as an unresolved import?

Comment: Hi Fabio, I tried your suggestion and I still get an error :-(